# PNG area chart with Google Charts API?

Tags: perl, png, google-visualization

I want to make an area chart with Google's Chart API, but it needs to be the PNG format one so I can build a PDF. Is that possible? The [Chart Wizard](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html) does not seem to support area charts. Also, I want to do it in perl and the URI::GoogleChart module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a lot of time on this and discovered that I can do this:

[See the example visually](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1%3a|week1|week2&chxp=1,20,90&chxr=0,0,120&chxs=0,676767,11.5,0.5,l,676767|1,676767,9.5,0,_,676767&chxt=y,x&chs=300x278&cht=lxy&chco=FF9900,FF0000&chds=6.667,100,0,110,0,100,0,118.333&chd=t%3a-1|110,80|-1|43,32&chdl=Total%20Num|Special%20Num&chdlp=t&chg=1,-1,1,0&chls=2|2&chma=8,0,0,7|54,2&chtt=%23+Total+and+%23+Red+Items&chts=000000,11.5&chm=b,FF9900,0,1,0|B,FF0000,1,9,0) or the code below:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart
   ?chxl=1:|week1|week2
   &chxp=1,20,90
   &chxr=0,0,120
   &chxs=0,676767,11.5,0.5,l,676767|1,676767,9.5,0,_,676767
   &chxt=y,x
   &chs=300x278
   &cht=lxy
   &chco=FF9900,FF0000
   &chds=6.667,100,0,110,0,100,0,118.333
   &chd=t:-1|110,80|-1|43,32
   &chdl=Total+Num|Special+Num
   &chdlp=t
   &chg=1,-1,1,0
   &chls=2|2
   &chma=8,0,0,7|54,2
   &chtt=%23+Total+and+%23+Red+Items
   &chts=000000,11.5
   &chm=b,FF9900,0,1,0|B,FF0000,1,9,0
```

Where the last line **b,color,startLine,endLine,0** means fill down to *endLine* and **B,color,startLine,arbitraryNumber,0** means fill down to the bottom of the chart.

The solution came from [Google's docs](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_params.html#gcharts_chof) with some experimentation.

Comment: Actually, you can create this in the chart wizard under Markers -> Fill Marker (for B) and Bounded Fill Marker (for b).